# Merge Sort : Bugs in this code

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I get index out of bounds exception when i try to run this code .

we are using two different array s left and right for merging ..

and using recursive merge sort to divide the array into individaul elements and merging them...

Here's the algorithm from CLRS i am using :

```
    Merge(A, p, q, r)
    n1 ← q - p + 1
    n2 ← r - q
    create arrays L[1..n1 + 1] and R[1..n2 + 1]
    for i ← 1 to n1
    do L[i] ← A[p + i - 1]
    for j ← 1 to n2
      do R[j] ← A[q + j]
    L[n1 + 1] ← ∞
    L[n2 + 1] ← ∞
    i ← 1
    j ← 1
    for k ≤ p to r
        do if L[i] ≤ R[j]
          then A[k] ← L[i]
             i ← i + 1
          else A[k] ← R[j]
              j ← j + 1

     MergeSort(A, p, r)
     if p < r
      then q ← ⌊(p + r)/2⌋
       MergeSort(A, p, q)
       MergeSort(A, q + 1, r)
       Merge(A, p, q, r)
```

here's the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MergeSort {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the size of array to be sorted");
      int size = input.nextInt();
      int[] A = new int[size];
      System.out.println("Enter the elements of array");
      for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
         A[i] = input.nextInt();
      }
      System.out.println("The UNSORTED array elements are" + Arrays.toString(A));
      int p = 0, r = size;
      mergeSort(A, p, r);
      System.out.println("The SORTED array elements are" + Arrays.toString(A));
   }

   public static void mergeSort(int[] A, int p, int r) {
      if (p < r) {
         int q = (p + r) / 2;
         mergeSort(A, p, q);
         mergeSort(A, q + 1, r);
         merge(A, p, q, r);
      }
   }

   public static void merge(int[] A, int p, int q, int r) {
      int n1 = q - p + 1;
      int n2 = r - q;
      int[] L = new int[n1 + 1];
      int[] R = new int[n2 + 1];
      L[n1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      R[n2] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
         L[i] = A[p + i];
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
         R[j] = A[q + j + 1];
      }
      int x = 0, y = 0;
      for (int k = p; k < r; k++) {
         if (L[x] <= R[y]) {
            A[k] = L[x];
            x++;
         } else {
            A[k] = R[y];
            y++;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: User println statements to check the state of variables just before the exception is thrown. In particular check the length of the array A, and the value of all the variables that combined make the index to the A array.

Comment: Possibly you could at least confide in us which line gets the exception, but just dumping your entire assignment here to be done by somebody else isn't likely to find much favor at SO, or anywhere else I can think of. There are plenty of working examples on the net.

Comment: that is not an assignment ... i dont go to school . it's just small error that i couldnt notice ..as pointed out by @Gandalf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a second but longer look, your implementation of the algorithm seems to be right, i got confused regarding your input parameters because they did not fit your zero based implementation. So maybe you do not want to call it like this:

```
int p = 0, r = size;
mergeSort(A, p, r);
```

but rather like this:

```
int p = 0, r = size - 1;
mergeSort(A, p, r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, and after the change that Gandalf suggested, in the `merge()` method the for loop should include the value of r, so by replacing

```
for (int k = p; k < r; k++) {
```

with

```
for (int k = p; k <= r; k++) {
```

your implementation sorts the array correctly.